# Use a versioning tool (svn, git) in a solo project

Tags: versioning

Have you ever experienced the use of versioning system in a solo project? Is usefull? 
What your experience?

Comment: I use VCS of one form or another for almost everything I do. LaTeX documents and programming in particular. Remote copies and a history is unbelievably useful.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're not using it for collaboration purposes, using version control frees you to experiment without worrying about breaking existing code. You can try an experiment in a new branch, and either throw the branch away if it doesn't pan out or merge it into your mainline if you want to keep it.

Having a well-known way of keeping backup copies is useful as well (pushing to a repository stored on an external drive or across the network).